# ASP.NET Controls in UpdatePanel not working after File Upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm new to working with the AJAX UpdatePanel and I've tried searching for an answer to this question and haven't found a solution yet.

I have multiple controls in an UpdatePanel since I am hiding and showing panels based on different button clicks. Also inside the UpdatePanel is a FileUpload control. Everything works fine until I upload a file. After that, none of the controls, like buttons or radio button lists, or JQuery scripts, like a datepicker, fire in the UpdatePanel after the upload.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Site.Admin" %>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/Site1.master"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function pageLoad() { 
            $(function () { 
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

                function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                    $('.picker').datetimepicker();
                }
            }); 
        } 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="adminUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_EndDate" class="form-control picker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_Active" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_Active_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="4" AutoPostBack="True">
                                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Upload Photo</label>
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="imageFileUpload" runat="server" />                                    
                                        <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="btn_UploadImg" runat="server" Text="Upload Image" OnClick="btn_UploadImg_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btn_CancelImg" OnClick="btn_CancelImg_Click" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Change/Remove Image" CausesValidation="False" />
                            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code behind relating to the file upload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(this.btn_UploadImg);
        }

protected void btn_UploadImg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool isUploaded = uploadImage(imageFileUpload);
            if (isUploaded)
            {                
                btn_CancelImg.Visible = true;

            }
        }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It worked fine when run from Visual Studio, but when pushed to the server it all fails

Comment: Start by giving the button that starts the file upload an PostBack Trigger in the UpdatePanel. Or place the FileUpload Control outside the UpdatePanel and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried using a trigger, but that didn't work. I'm working on rewriting my aspx page to move the FileUpload outside of the UpdatePanel. I was hoping there was a way I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting **Visible** to true/false, can you please try:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlToHide" runat="server" style="display:none">
```

When you have to show, you can use the following:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlToHide.Attributes["style"] = "display: '';";
}
```

Also, you can try ***fullpostback/render*** by using:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFileUpload"/>
</Triggers>
```